# How to create an array of ObservableList and initialize them in a loop for JavaFX Table

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, observablelist

I am trying to create a tournament application that simulates different tournament. I am using javaFX. The question here is I want to display several tables for the different group stages i.e. Group 1, Group2 etc.. I have created an array of tables and table columns and all works well but I don't know how to create an array of `ObservableList` objects to pass into the respective table. I want to create the array of `ObservableList` in a loop and initialize the variables in a loop as well to make it flexible. Here is the code of my controller class:

```
package com.solutioninventors.tournament.GUI.StandingTable.copy;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

/**
 * @author ChineduKnight
 */
public class StandingTableController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    ScrollPane sp;
    TableView<StandingTable> table[];
    TableColumn<StandingTable, String> name[];
    TableColumn<StandingTable, Double> WDLFADP[][];
    String tableLabel[] = {"P","W","D","L","GF","GA","GD","PTS"};
    String standingTableValue[] = {"gamesPlayed","wins","draw","loss","goalsFor","goalsAgainst","goalsDiff","points"};
    int noOfRounds = 3;
    private VBox vBox;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setupTable() {
        name = new TableColumn[noOfRounds]; 
           for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                 name[i] = new TableColumn<>("Competitor Name");
                 name[i].setMinWidth(200);
                 name[i].setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("competitorName"));
            }//end for loop for name setup

           WDLFADP = new TableColumn[noOfRounds][8];  
           for (int row = 0; row < WDLFADP.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < WDLFADP[row].length; col++) {
                    WDLFADP[row][col] = new TableColumn<>(tableLabel[col]);
                    WDLFADP[row][col].setMinWidth(5);
                    WDLFADP[row][col].setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(standingTableValue[col]));

                }
            }
         //is there a way to make this list1 and list2 in an array
          // and initalize them in a loop as well? 
        ObservableList<StandingTable> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(

                new StandingTable("Manu", 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4), 
                new StandingTable("Arsenal", 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4),
                new StandingTable("Chelsea", 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4)

        );
        ObservableList<StandingTable> list2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(

                new StandingTable("Everton", 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4),
                new StandingTable("Liverpool", 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4), 
                new StandingTable("ManCity", 5, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4)

        );
        table = new TableView[noOfRounds];

        //how do I pass in multiple list
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            table[i] = new TableView<>();
            table[i].setItems(list);//here is the problem
            table[i].getColumns().add(name[i]);
            for (int col = 0; col < WDLFADP[i].length; col++) {
                table[i].getColumns().add(WDLFADP[i][col]);
            }
        }//end outer for loop
    }// end table setup



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        setupTable();//call utility method
        Label lbl[] = new Label[noOfRounds];
        for (int i = 0; i < lbl.length; i++) {
            lbl[i] = new Label("Group "+(i+1));
        }
        vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfRounds; i++) {
            vBox.getChildren().add(lbl[i]);
            vBox.getChildren().add(table[i]);
        }//end for loop
        sp.setContent(vBox);
    }

}// end class
```

Comment: You can't create an array of a generic type of object. Create a `List<ObservableList<StandingTable>>` instead.

Comment: @James_D thanks for the quick response I have tried your answer but I am still having problems with the instantiation ie how to pass in values to the List<ObservableList<StandingTable>>